# Redshift Query Scheduler is State: Enabled but the queries are not running. IAM Permission problem?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, data-warehouse

I am attempting to use the Redshift Scheduler to run an UNLOAD to S3. The database is connected properly and when I connect and run the query from the Console it runs. I have enabled a scheduled query to run every hour, but it is not executing.

Am I missing something? I have set up the IAM role with the AmazonRedshiftFullAccess and Secret Manager access. The Trust Policy has scheduler.redshift.amazonaws.com and redshift.amazonaws.com as trusted entity providers and can assume role as my user.

I'm not getting any errors, it just is not running. State is enabled, but the S3 bucket is not updating and there are no query records in the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add the EventBridge permissions - events.amazonaws.com as a trusted provider and AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess policy.

Comment: This answer resolved my problem as well.  The AWS documentation is rather lacking in this regard.  In case its helpful, this is what worked for me in its entirety.  Policies: "AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess", "AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess".  Trust relationships: scheduler.redshift.amazonaws.com, events.amazonaws.com, and my user ARN.

Answer (score 0):

Using CloudFormation I had to set the `StatementName` in `RedshiftDataParameters` to the same `Name` as the `Rule`

```
  MyRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(0/1 * ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN *)"
      Name: "my-rule"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:redshift:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster:${RedshiftClusterName}"
          Id: "my-target-id"
          RoleArn: !GetAtt RoleFromUpTop.Arn
          RedshiftDataParameters:
            Database: "my_db"
            DbUser: "my_user"
            Sql: "SELECT * FROM some_table;"
            StatementName: "my-rule"
```